# How to set initial value in Select tag in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, drop-down-menu

There is a **Select** tag, for which I want to have an initial value and set that initial value to variable **name**, the select tag:

```
<Field
  name="data.account"
  render={({ field: { name, ...restFieldProps } }) => (
    <Column>
      <Select
        {...restFieldProps}
        value={pl =>
          setFieldValue(name, pl)
        }
        onChange={value => setFieldValue(name, value)}
        placeholder={pl}
        width={300}
        disabled={false}
      >
        <SelectOption value="k1" label="v1" />;
        <SelectOption value="k2" label="v2" />;
      </Select>

    </Column>
  )}
/>
```

The problem is, whenever I select something from the drop-down, the variable gets initialized, but not otherwise.

Basically, the `onChange` is getting called and set the value when I select something from the drop-down list, but it's not getting set when I don't click the drop-down, to handle that I have written the **value** option in the **Select** tag, but it's not working.

Could anyone please suggest what might be wrong in this Select tag?

(Note: pl is a variable which is having correct value, verified by adding that in placeholder)

Comment: Why are you passing a function to the `value` prop? Just pass a value. Value should be whatever `fieldValue` is. And you can initialize `fieldValue` to whatever default value you want.

Comment: OK, but I guess it will not set that value to the variable "name" or will it?

Comment: What do you want it to do? Where are you storing the selected value in state? What is the variable called?

Comment: the variable is "account", basically I want to call setFieldValue function without someone clicking the drop down list, want to replicate whats happening on the "onChange" function.

Comment: "I want to have a initial value and set that initial value to variable name". Is "name" one of your options? Can I select it if I change the select value? You need some state that stores the currently selected variable - const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState("hello"). You need to set value prop as the selected value - `value={selectedValue}`. When the selection changes, change the state value - `onChange={setSelectedValue}`.

Comment: No, the "name"(data.account) is the field which would be set and sent as a parameter to an api, setFieldValue is setting it correctly in "onChange", but it's not working as expected in the "value" parameter of Select tag

Comment: You don't want to call `setFieldValue`, because you don't want to set the field value, you want it to ALREADY BE SET. Just initialize it to the default value.

Comment: The `value` prop does not accept a function, it accepts a value. You can't give it a function, especially not a setter function. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: started working on react just a few days ago, not much idea about react, the above mentioned solution didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have to write selected option in SelectOption like this,

```js
<Field
  name="data.account"
  render={({ field: { name, ...restFieldProps } }) => (
    <Column>
      <Select
        {...restFieldProps}
        value={pl =>
          setFieldValue(name, pl)
        }
        onChange={value => setFieldValue(name, value)}
        placeholder={pl}
        width={300}
        disabled={false}
      >
        <SelectOption value="k1" label="v1"  selected={true}/>;
        <SelectOption value="k2" label="v2" />;
      </Select>

    </Column>
  )}
/>
```

Comment: the problem is this SelectOption is getting generated dynamically by iterating through a list, didn't write it here for simplicity, wouldn't know which SelectOption to make selected

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see, you mean like this?

```js
something.map(item => 
const isSelected = item === initialValue;
return   <SelectOption value="k1" label="v1"  selected={isSelected}/>;
})
```

or

```js
something.map(item => 
const isSelected = item === fieldValuee;
return   <SelectOption value="k1" label="v1"  selected={isSelected}/>;
})
```

Comment: got an error: Value must be omitted for boolean attributes, tried with selected= "true", it didn't work